# Meteor quick start template

Tags: meteor

I am very new to meteor but have a very good experience with knockout and angular, trying to learn meteor. Is there any jump start template for meteor just like Angular Hottowel ?

If not then what is the best way to create a simple Responsive UI with a side bar, navigation and footer using meteor ? Any suggestions for packages or existing code from meteor examples ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Core Team

Well, this might be a hacky way of doing it, but Meteor's core team sample todos application has sidebar and navigation.  You can test drive it by running this from your CLI:

`meteor create --example todos`

and then running it with `meteor run` and taking a look at the code.

#### Yeoman

Now, if you are looking for a simpler generator, like Hottowel, have you looked at yeoman generators?  Once you've installed yeoman, you can add meteor generator:

`$ npm install -g generator-meteor`

and then `yo meteor`.

#### Atmosphere

Finally, look around https://atmospherejs.com/.

It is the source for meteor packages, and you can easily add things like sidebars or twitter bootstrap via command line.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I do not have any experience with Yeoman, but i will try that, yesterday i did look at atmosphere looks like it does have few good packages to start with. I added bootstrap and jquery and copied a sample navigation bar html from http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar   but its not coming up nicely, not sure why

Comment: Bootstrap with fontawesome is working perfectly now with meteor on windows. I had to install them manaully, built in bootstrap package was not working correctly with the code samples i was using from bootstrap site. For details to install bootstrap and font awesome manaually ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944194/how-to-manually-load-fontawesome-4-in-meteor-js

Comment: I am stuck add adding iron router. Can you please tell me how to add iron router on windows ? or you can answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266117/cannot-add-package-iron-router-for-meteor-on-windows-8-1-pro